# Google Maps Places API - Add/Delete place functionality being removed

Tags: google-maps-api-3

as stated here:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place

The Add/Delete place functionality is being removed.

As stated here:
https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent replacement for add/delete place.

Can anyone inform me if there will be a way to add places in the context of an app, ie. add a place that can only be seen and referenced by an individual app, after this part of the API is removed?

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem like there is any documentation for a replacement, my tip is to keep an eye open for any updates, but create a map using the js version of the API Where you have a lot more Free room to play with the map.

I tried to find a Google Maps embed api updates page, But could only find One for the Js version.

I know it isnt a direct answer to Your question, But to Your exact question i think i would answer no.

- Herman